# ValueError unknown url type when trying to create the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use `open(os.path.abspath(os.curdir) + "/children.csv", "w")` to create and write the data into the file in the current directory. When I run this command I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: '/Users/EL-CAPITAN-2016/Downloads/children.csv'
```

I tried using just `open("children.csv","w")`, but it gave me the same error. 
I tried creating the file manually and using its URL to just read the file using `open("/Users/EL-CAPITAN-2016/Downloads/children.csv","r")` but again same error

**The code to create and write into the file**:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as open
import os
print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
f = open(os.path.abspath(os.curdir) + '/children.csv','w')
```

**The code I used to read the file that I created manually**:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as open
import os
print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
f = open('/Users/EL-CAPITAN-2016/Downloads/children.csv','r')
```

**The error logs I receive are the following**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "children.py", line 7, in <module>
    f = open('children.csv','r')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 510, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: '/Users/EL-CAPITAN-2016/Downloads/children.csv''
```

Comment: Please post your whole code.

Comment: Sorry, will do so right now

Comment: The error stack shows `urllib/request.py` which makes me thing the builtin `open()` is replaced by `urllib.urlopen()`

Comment: Thanks so much, i just found a bug in my code!

Comment: Okay, what was the issue?

Comment: when I was debugging I forgot to delete the line (it was at the very top of the file and i  didnt even see it there), you can now see it in the code as: "from urllib.request import urlopen as open" which caused the issue

Comment: @DinDaniyarbekov always gotta be careful when renaming imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shuvojit & OP figured out, the issue was the import of `urlopen` as `open` replacing the builtin `open`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as open
```